# Django authentication not producing proper html

Tags: django

I've got a problem with Django's authentication and login views. I've been following the official documentation with regards to creating a custom login: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

I've created a custom login view:

```
def myLogin(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse('main'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('login'))

    return render(request, "login.html", {'user': user})
```

and here's my template, which is copied from the official documents: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

my urls look like this:

```
from authentication.views import myLogin
from users.views import baseView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^main/', baseView, name='main'),
    url(r'^login/', myLogin, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

When I try to access the login page it produces the page, but only the login button, not the form fields needed to write the username and password. Why is this happening? When using the built-in login, the login function works as intended, but I'm afraid I can't use it as I need some additional functionality down the line.

Answer (score 0):

in your mylogin view  you don't pass any login form so in your template you pass a form variable which is correct but because it's empty django don't display any form

so in your function based view you must create a login form

```
def myLogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       myloginform = LoginForm(request.POST)
       username = request.POST.get('username')
       password = request.POST.get('password')
       user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
       if user is not None:
           if user.is_active:
               login(request, user)
               return redirect(reverse('main'))
           else:
              return redirect(reverse('login'))
   else:
     myloginform = LoginForm()
   return render(request, "login.html", {'form': myloginform})
```